# Validate and Add Service Provider/Location in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a button that will validate the textbox for the service provider and the dropdown list for the locations. I have 3 tables: Locations, Service_Providers, and Service_Providers_Locations with a many-to-many relationship. But the tables that are affected are mainly Service_Providers and Service_Providers_Locations. However, upon running, the button inserts the record even if there are duplicates. What we want is to not allow duplicate record in the transaction table Service_Providers_Locations. There can be the same name of service provider, but not same location. Our code allows duplicate record insertion. We are using a three-tier approach.

```
protected void btnAddServiceProvider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bll.Name = txtServiceProvider.Text;
        DataTable temp = bll.ServiceProviderCheckExisting();
        if (temp.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            bll.IsDeleted = "n";
            bll.ServiceProviderAdd();
            temp = bll.ServiceProviderCheckExisting();
            bll.ServiceProviderID = temp.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
            bll.IsApproved = "y";
            bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
            gvServiceProviders.DataSource = bll.GetServiceProviderLocations();
            gvServiceProviders.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            bll.ServiceProviderID = temp.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            temp = bll.GetServiceProviderLocationUsingServiceProviderID();
            if (temp.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
                bll.IsApproved = "y";
                bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
                gvServiceProviders.DataSource = bll.GetServiceProviderLocations();
                gvServiceProviders.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < temp.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (ddlLocations.SelectedValue == temp.Rows[x][1].ToString())
                    {
                        lblServiceProviderError.Text = "This service provider already exists for that location.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
                        bll.IsApproved = "y";
                        bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
                        gvServiceProviders.DataSource = bll.GetServiceProviderLocations();
                        gvServiceProviders.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this code insert duplicates ?

Comment: @Heslacher yes it does. I believe that the for loop is responsible for this. But I have yet to figure out how and why.

Comment: Would you mind reformatting the text a little bit, so that it is easier to read ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have placed the insertion outside of the `for` loop and created a `boolean` variable that will change when the program in the `for` loop runs in the first `if` statement. It now works as I wanted it to be.

```
bool isExisting = false;
for (int x = 0; x < temp.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    if (ddlLocations.SelectedValue == temp.Rows[x][1].ToString())
    {
        lblServiceProviderError.Text = "Service provider already exists.";
        isExisting = true;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
if (isExisting == false)
{
    bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
    bll.IsApproved = "y";
    bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
    gvServiceProviders.DataSource = bll.GetServiceProviderLocations();
    gvServiceProviders.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The `continue;` in the else is superfluous, and thus the whole `else` block. Nobody writes `if (isExisting == false)`, instead we write `if (!isExisting)`. Even better would be to avoid this negative check and invert the logic, i.e. `bool addProviderLocation = true;` etc. so you'd get `if (addProviderLocation)`.

Answer (score 8):

There are five lines that are repeated three times:

```
bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
bll.IsApproved = "y";
bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
gvServiceProviders.DataSource = bll.GetServiceProviderLocations();
gvServiceProviders.DataBind();
```

Those should be moved to a separate method to start with. I also don't like that it does two things: update `bll` and then use `bll` to update `gvServiceProviders`; this looks like a mix of UI and business logic.

---

`temp` is a really bad name.

---

At this point we're basically here, if you apply some techniques to reduce the indentation:

```
protected void btnAddServiceProvider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bll.Name = txtServiceProvider.Text;
    DataTable temp = bll.ServiceProviderCheckExisting();

    if (temp.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        bll.IsDeleted = "n";
        bll.ServiceProviderAdd();
        temp = bll.ServiceProviderCheckExisting();
        bll.ServiceProviderID = temp.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        Update();
        return;
    }

    bll.ServiceProviderID = temp.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    temp = bll.GetServiceProviderLocationUsingServiceProviderID();

    if (temp.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Update();
        return;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < temp.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        if (ddlLocations.SelectedValue == temp.Rows[x][1].ToString())
        {
            lblServiceProviderError.Text = "This service provider already exists for that location.";
        }
        else
        {
            Update();
        }
    }       
}
```

(`Update()` is the method that contains the five lines I mentioned at the beginning. Not a  great method name either.)

Which I find to be an odd flow, to say the least. Which is partly due to not knowing what `bll` actually is.

To me it feels like some of the code should be re-thought. For instance this:

```
bll.LocationID = ddlLocations.SelectedValue;
bll.IsApproved = "y";
bll.ServiceProviderLocationAdd();
```

Why isn't this one single method on `bll` that takes the value of `ddlLocations.SelectedValue` as a parameter?

I'm also not fond of `ServiceProviderCheckExisting()` returning a `DataTable`, I'd expect it to be more like `GetExisting()`.